# Illustrator text alignment

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typesetting, formatting

I want my text to produce exact outcome of 'justify all lines'. i took text, dragged it, created a box (exactly the size i want my paragraph to be in) and then applied 'justify all lines' from paragraph option.

but it creates huge gap/space between words (look at disease and management). and it destroys all aesthetic vibe. if i delete the space my letter gets deleted too. and if i modify the box size it is still not removing all those unnecessary [image]spaces.

what i need to do to get 'justify all lines' result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all *Justify all lines* might not be the best choice. When you force all lines to be justified the last line will often look bad. It's a coincidence if your text will look good, not all texts can be layout like this simply because of the number of letters.

Instead you should try using *Justify with last line aligned left* and accept that the last line doesn't have the same width as the others.

Secondly, you must make sure that your text doesn't contain any line breaks. It looks like there is a line break after "disease," which forces this word to fill the entire width of the text box.

You can turn on *Type > Show Hidden Characters* to check if your text is free of manual line breaks.

Comment: Bonus tips: Correct *"diabetes ,thyroid"* to *"diabetes, thyroid"* (the space isn't placed correctly) and correct *"liver & kidney"* to *"liver and kidney"* (& is mostly used in headers and it's inconsistent with the "and" two lines below).

Comment: Thank you so much. yes you are right. the last line is hideous... so long i was keep trying to make them fit... and thank you for the bonus tips as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Justify will never work with a text column so narrow.

There is nothing you can do in the settings to make that specific setup work. Instead, use left align, or change the design so that text box is much wider if you really need to justify.

Comment: Thank you Lucian. yeah i have learnt that after wasting much time. :(

Comment: It is called learning.

Comment: Right you are :)